# How to use ggbetweenstats with grouped data at different timepoints in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I'm trying to use the `ggbetweenstats` function from the `ggstatsplot` package in R version 4.3.2 to create a plot showing the spread of some data between 2 different treatment groups at 3 different time points.

All I've found so far is the `grouped_ggbetweenstats` function which produces a `facet_wrap` type effect with the treatment groups rather than a single plot. I could just use a `geom_boxplot` via `ggplot2` and include stats with the `ggsignif` package, but I really like the plots made by `ggbetweenstats`.

Here's my data:

```
Treatment <- sample(c("A", "B"), 100, replace=T) 
Timepoint <- sample(c("1", "2", "3"), 100, replace=T) 
Value <- sample(20:80, size=100, replace=T) 
df <- data.frame(Treatment, Timepoint, Value) 
library(ggstatsplot)
```

What I've tried so far, producing the two separate plots:

```
grouped_ggbetweenstats(data=df, x=Timepoint, y=Value,
                       grouping.var=Treatment, results.subtitle=F)
```

[image: Plot1]

What I would like to create instead:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() + 
  geom_boxplot(data=df, aes(x=Timepoint, y=Value, color=Treatment))
```

[image: Plot2]

Is there any way to use the `ggstatsplot` package to create this type of plot, or would I need to combine `geom_boxplot`, `geom_point`, `geom_violin`, `geom_signif`, etc.?

Comment: While I recognize that this may be slightly off-topic, I've often found overlaying boxplots and violin plots to be somewhat vexing. The tradeoff in aesthetics, in my opinion, doesn't seem to be adequately compensated by any discernible enhancement in visualization; if anything, they might even be less effective in that regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `ggstatsplot` does have a nice look, but as with many extension packages that aim to make it easy to produce professional results, it can be harder to coax it to give you more bespoke outputs. It's not terribly difficult to replicate the look using pure ggplot if you want to then add `ggsignif` comparisons and the `ggrepel` labels.

The following is produced entirely without `ggstatsplot`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(ggsignif)

ggplot(df, aes(Timepoint, Value, group = interaction(Timepoint, Treatment))) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Treatment, fill = after_scale(alpha(colour, 0.5))), 
             position = position_jitterdodge(dodge.width = 0.9, 0.1),
             size = 3, shape = 21) +
  geom_boxplot(fill = NA, color = "black", width = 0.2, linewidth = 0.4,
               position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
  geom_violin(fill = NA, color = "black", width = 0.6, linewidth = 0.4,
              position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
  geom_point(stat = "summary", size = 5, color = "#8a0f00",
             position = position_dodge(0.9), fun = mean) +
  geom_label_repel(stat = "summary", fun = mean, size = 3.5,
                   aes(label = paste0("hat(mu)*scriptstyle(mean)==", 
                                      round(after_stat(y), 2))),
                   parse = TRUE, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
  geom_signif(y_position = 85, xmin = 1:3 - 0.22, xmax = 1:3 + 0.22,
              annotations = scales::pvalue(sapply(split(df, df$Timepoint), 
                            \(x) wilcox.test(Value~Treatment, x)$p.value),
                                           add_p = TRUE)) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~., 
          bquote(Pairwise~Test~paste(":")~bold(Wilcoxon~Test)))) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set2") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 12) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(face = 2),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        axis.text.y.right = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: This was very helpful! It works perfectly with my reproducible example data, but for some reason when I use it in my real dataset, I'm able to generate the complete plot except for the geom_signif comparisons. Would anyone have an idea as to why this could be? As far as I can tell I've gotten the syntax (df and column names) for my real data correct, and set the y axis limits correctly. Maybe I'm missing something else about the annotation segment? I know that isn't much to go on but if anyone has solved a similar issue I'd love to hear!

Comment: Wanted to add that I also cannot seem to do this (add the within-time point comparisons) manually as described in the bar plot on the ggsignif page: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggsignif/vignettes/intro.html. I can do the  between group/time point comparisons, though.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an attempt by using `ggstatsplot::ggbetweenstats` while creating our own `x` values by combining `Treatment` and `Timepoint`. You can use `scale_x_...` functions to change your x-axis ticks if needed. However, This won't give you the same colors for each `Treatment`.

```r
library(ggstatsplot)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Timepoint_dodge = as.factor(paste(Treatment, Timepoint, sep = "-")),
         Timepoint_dodge = factor(Timepoint_dodge, 
                levels = unique(Timepoint_dodge[order(Timepoint, Treatment)]), 
                ordered = T)) %>% 
  ggbetweenstats(data=., x=Timepoint_dodge, y=Value, results.subtitle=F)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-12-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

#### Update:

We can update the colors afterwards:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Timepoint_dodge = as.factor(paste(Treatment, Timepoint, sep = "-")),
         Timepoint_dodge = factor(Timepoint_dodge, 
                levels = unique(Timepoint_dodge[order(Timepoint, Treatment)]), 
                ordered = T)) %>% 
  ggbetweenstats(data=., x=Timepoint_dodge, y=Value, results.subtitle=F) -> gg


gg$layers[[1]]$mapping$colour <- rlang::new_quosure(df$Treatment)

gg
```

[image]